# What kind of Database Testing could be done based on soapui trnasactions?

Tags: soapui

The transactions are SoapUi transactions but the effect of them is that the database is updated.

What sort of test cases or approaches can I use in this situation?

Comment: SOAPUI is not really intended for database testing, it can access databases via JDBC and Groovy the intent is to support data driven testing of APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Although SOAPUI is NOT for database testing, perhaps you can test the effects on the database as with any messaging system.

- Does a successful 'new' message create the database object as expected ?
- Is an unsuccessful 'new' message (source format invalid) handled correctly ?
- Is an unsuccessful 'new' message (source format valid but dependency issue) handled correctly?
- Is an unsuccessful 'new' message (source format valid but db issue)  handled correctly ?
- Does a valid 'update' message actually update the final database as intended ?
- Does an invalid 'update' message leave the database unchanged as intended ?